# "If I was rich, I would have bought..." vs. "If I was rich, I would buy..."

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Is it correct to answer *if it was* or *were* with “would have”?

Example:

> If I was rich, I **would have** bought a car.

Or should it be only would?

> If I was rich, I **would** buy a car.

If the answer is the former, why is it?

Comment: I think that answers to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/660/when-to-use-if-i-was-vs-if-i-were) would be helpful.

Comment: If I were a rich man I would buy a car.

Comment: The first describes the past, the second, the future. However, If-was works best to argue against a statement, and If-were works best for imagined possibilities. You say I was rich but drove a bike -- I say "Untrue, since if *I was* rich, I would have bought a car (and I couldn't cause I wasn't)." Or, "Was I rich then? That might have been nice. If *I were* rich, I would have bought a car."

Answer (score 2):

**Past counterfactuals**

To talk about a counterfactual in the past, you usually use the past perfect in the subordinate clause, then the conditional perfect in the main clause:

- If I **had been** rich, I **would have bought** a car.

**Hypotheticals**

To talk about an alternative present or a hypothetical future, you use the simple past in the subordinate clause, then the conditional in the main clause:

- If I **was** rich, I **would buy** a car.

Some speakers prefer the "were" form here (which can replace "was" when a hypothetical is being discussed):

- If I **were** rich, I **would buy** a car.

However, you could also combine the hypothetical wealth with a perfect verb:

- If I **was/were** rich, I **would have bought** a car.

Here the sense is that you would have already bought it, possibly some time ago, not simply that would be about to buy it.

Answer (score 0):

Best to go back to the "was" and change it to "were" to match the tense of the the first example.  The second sentence is probably fine with either "was" or "were."

Answer (score 0):

1. If I were\had been rich five years ago, I would have bought that car. (I'm rich now)
2. If I was rich, I would have bought that car we saw yesterday. (I'm still not rich)
3. If I was rich, I would buy a car. (I'm not rich)

Answer (score 0):

"If I was rich I would have bought a car" means that if the speaker was rich, they would have bought a car; that is, it would be in the **past**.

In "If I was rich I would buy a car", the speaker means that, in a hypothetical situation where they gained a lot  of money, they would buy a car.

Generally, in the first situation someone, the speaker may be trying to do that thing, while in the second the speaker is merely pondering what he/she would buy if they had sufficient money.